# Creative ways to improve URL load/render performance in Windows app

Tags: javascript, windows, performance, dns, web

I am developing a Windows desktop app for my self hosted website. It has a native shell with hosted web-browser/webview control. Right now, once user launches the app, it opens the site's home page in its webview. Since the app will be sitting on the clients' machine, I wonder if we can do something to improve the load/render performance in cold boot (first launch) scenario. There are few areas I can think of. Coming from a non-web dev experience, all my thoughts are just theories and I don't know if they are possible to achieve.

1. Cache DNS locally through code so that when the url is requested, we already have the DNS cached locally and we don't waste time in DNS lookup
2. Do something with TCP handshake. Pre-establish the connection (In a separate thread?) so that when the url is requested, the TCP connection with the server is already established and the request is immediately served

Since my website is self hosted (which means we know what's gonna change in future and what not), Fiddler's traces can tell us about the URLs to pre-cache the DNS and pre-establish the TCP connection.
**Does this make sense? Right now, I am in the prototype phase and want to try if this really works. I also wonder if above mentioned things are feasible.**
**Is there anything else I can try?**

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to improve first launch speeds, other than moving to a professional host, or making your website smaller. DNS lookup and TCP handshakes occur in a matter of milliseconds. If you really need the website to load faster, and It has slow-changing, dynamic content, you might want to consider cloudflare railgun.